# How To Create A Line Chart From HTML Table?

Tags: jquery, html, charts, linechart

I am new to this chart concept and mvc. I am trying to create a line chart for the table data in mvc. here is the sample data that i am using..

```
<div class="panel-body table-responsive">
        <table id="dtView" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-response">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-center">Package Name</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Jan</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Feb</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Mar</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Apr</th>
                    <th class="text-center">May</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Jun</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Jul</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Aug</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Sep</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Oct</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Nov</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Dec</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                <tr>
                    <td>Hyderabad</td>
                    <td>123151</td>
                    <td>234324</td>
                    <td>234234</td>
                    <td>12333</td>
                    <td>45644</td>
                    <td>2344</td>
                    <td>45666</td>
                    <td>2344</td>
                    <td>9877</td>
                    <td>3232444</td>
                    <td>344355</td>
                    <td>34555</td>
                    <td>345566</td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Bangalore</td>
                    <td>12321151</td>
                    <td>232214324</td>
                    <td>232334234</td>
                    <td>14342333</td>
                    <td>44555644</td>
                    <td>2334365644</td>
                    <td>45434666</td>
                    <td>2323344</td>
                    <td>98212177</td>
                    <td>32343532444</td>
                    <td>344545355</td>
                    <td>345323255</td>
                    <td>3455454566</td>

                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

to be frank i don't know how to create... so, please help me.. thank you..

Comment: Tag your question properly. Are you planning to do this in C#, `Javascript`, or what?

Comment: Check https://developers.google.com/chart/?hl=en, more specifically: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart

Comment: @jstreet in jQuery ..!!!!

Comment: @MatthewJohnson thank you!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has a slick Charts API that is easy to use.  From the [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Month', 'Hyderabad', 'Bangalore'],
      ['Jan',  123151, 12321151],
      ['Feb',  234324, 232214324],
      ['March',  234234, 232334234]
      //more data here
    ]);

    var options = {
      //different options available
      title: 'Company Performance',
      curveType: 'function',
      legend: { position: 'bottom' }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

Word of warning, some of the charts might not work in IE8 and under.  This assumes that you have a container with an `id` of `curve-chart` to render the actual chart.

Comment: that's works fine with the static data... but how to handle the same dynamically, i mean if i had the "data" returned from controller and i want it be handled in ajax-call of jQuery.. @matthewjohnson

Comment: You'd just build an array of arrays by looping through the data returned.  Add an example of the response and I can update with an example. @htiru

Comment: @mattewjohnson:  here is the array data that i am having in my controller.. "  [{"Label":"Solapur","Data":[25836,94698,49,5149,465153,5329,6489371,11169,9369,9369,653149,645149]}]  "
now how to return this data as json to view and generate the chart in ajax-call.. i have tried to to pass the data like " return View(data) " which is not as json object.. thank you...!!!!

Comment: What controller and what language?  You might be better off asking a new question, but i'll help if i can @h :)

Comment: its in mvc(model-view-controller)

Comment: There are a ton of frameworks and languages that use MVC.  Glad you found it though.